# is it useful to use 'wait' after using linux GNU parallel?

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a question about **GNU parallel**.

I am using the software to parallelize a set of commands, but I am willing to wait all commands finish before quitting the main bash shell.

Is it useful to add:

```
1 paralle something
2 wait
```

after the parallel command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. GNU Parallel does the `wait` for you.

Comment: More specifically, by adding `parallel --colsep ' '` for the script to wait until the parallel execution is done as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69238775/2019974