# execute command only after gnu parallel runs all jobs

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have the bash file -

```sh
cat input.txt | parallel -j4 'python {}'

cp -r outputs /home/usr/my_outputs
```

I want to copy `outputs` to `my_outputs` only after all jobs finish executing. Presently, it looks like `parallel` returns immediately (after starting the jobs) and then `cp -r` is executed immediately, but I want to wait for the jobs to finish executing before I copy. How do I do this? Thanks!

EDIT:
input.txt is like -

```
run1.py -n 5 
run2.py -n 5 
run3.py -n 5 
run4.py -n 5
```

Comment: See: [is it useful to use 'wait' after using linux GNU parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53738766/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for your comment. From the link you sent, it looks like gnu-parallel does not return immediately. However when I run the bash script, I get an error with the cp command saying `outputs` does not exist. And this has to be because my python programs haven't executed as the folder `outputs` is created inside those programs.

Comment: I would continue troubleshooting runX.py.

Comment: Please show code for all scripts. Thank you.

Comment: Try `parallel --colsep ' '`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
parallel --colsep ' '
```

otherwise you are effectively trying to run:

```
python 'run1.py -n 5'
```

which means the Python interpreter is looking for a script called `run1.py -n 5`

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar where I have 4 python scripts running at once and had the same issue, though I was setting them off an pushing them to the background. These scripts wrote to files that were then used later in my bash script. I solved it by using `wait $(jobs -rp)` -

```
python script1.py & 
python script2.py & 
python script3.py & 
python script4.py & 
wait $(jobs -rp)

# other bash code that needs to run after the above
```

This works with gnu parallel as well. Try this:

```
cat input.txt | parallel -j4 'python {}'
wait $(jobs -rp)
cp -r outputs /home/usr/my_outputs
```

Comment: Not sure how this helps run **GNU Parallel** ?

Comment: Ya that wasn't a super clear answer I admit. That line `wait $(jobs -rp)` will work for gnu-parallel. I've edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: No. You don't need `wait` with **GNU Parallel**. Ever. It doesn't exit till all jobs are complete/failed.

Comment: I'm confused. If that's the case then why does OP have this problem?

Comment: Ok I saw your answer. Looks like `parallel --colsep ' '` works. Learned something new!