# use one txt file as input for GNU parallel and then use a second one after first one is finished

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Hi I have a command that uses echo and uses the commands in the cmds.txt and runs them parallel.

```
cat cmds1.txt | parallel -j4 --colsep ' ' -k echo {} | sshpass -p sftp xxx@localhost
```

I want to do something like this with gnu parallel but seen via [is it useful to use 'wait' after using linux GNU parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738766/is-it-useful-to-use-wait-after-using-linux-gnu-parallel)

GNU Parallel does the wait for you.

I want to run cmds2.txt only after cmds1.txt has finished but do not think using wait is right approach.

```
cat cmds1.txt | parallel -j4 --colsep ' ' -k echo {} | sshpass -p sftp xxx@localhost
wait $(jobs -rp)
cat cmds2.txt | parallel -j100 --colsep ' '-k --bar echo {} | sshpass -p sftp xxx@localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the wait:

```
cat cmds1.txt |
  parallel -j4 --colsep ' ' -k echo {} |
  sshpass -p sftp xxx@localhost
cat cmds2.txt |
  parallel -j100 --colsep ' '-k --bar echo {} |
  sshpass -p sftp xxx@localhost
```

But are you sure you do not want the `sftp`s to run in parallel?

```
cat cmds1.txt |
  parallel -j4 --colsep ' ' -k "echo {} | sshpass -p sftp xxx@localhost"
cat cmds2.txt |
  parallel -j100 --colsep ' '-k --bar "echo {} | sshpass -p sftp xxx@localhost"
```